# unable to integrate Persona SDK in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, persona

in my project i want to implementing  liveliness(selfie)detection by Persona.
for this i was use [persona_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/persona_flutter/versions/3.0.0-beta.0) in v2 channel.
but its crash after i open camera and taking a picture.

when i saw persona android sdk demo code,that provide in main side its working properly.
[persona-android-sdk](https://github.com/persona-id/persona-android-sdk)

**Project link is here**
https://github.com/jorgefspereira/persona_flutter/tree/v2

and in this project persona dependecy version is,

```
implementation "com.withpersona.sdk2:inquiry:2.2.9"
```

but,
as per persona documentation updated version we need to use.

```
implementation "com.withpersona.sdk2:inquiry:2.2.34"
```

but when i will updating this library lot of gradle issues arises.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform moshi-1.13.0.jar (com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.13.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.environment=standard-jvm, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /home/deq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.moshi/moshi/1.13.0/da685586facab9eb5c4fb630ce248be14e7da21b/moshi-1.13.0.jar.
         > Failed to transform '/home/deq/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.moshi/moshi/1.13.0/da685586facab9eb5c4fb630ce248be14e7da21b/moshi-1.13.0.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 60. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           Suggestions:
            - Check out existing issues at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:460323&s=modified_time:desc, it's possible that this issue has already been filed there.
            - If this issue has not been filed, please report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460323 (run with --stacktrace and provide a stack trace if possible).

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

even when i solve this issue with some research lot of other issue are arrising because my library verions is to older as compare to newer.

Comment: could you please add the full code you have done so far?

Comment: sure, i will update my question

Comment: can you share error log.

Comment: OK, i will share those as well in question, even when i solve this issue with some research lot of other issue are arising because my library version is to older as compare to newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is an outdated Gradle version.
I clone the Persona flutter project from GitHub.

Yes the project is working fine in version 2.2.9

```
implementation "com.withpersona.sdk2:inquiry:2.2.9"
```

But having an issue with version 2.2.34

```
implementation "com.withpersona.sdk2:inquiry:2.2.34"
```

I have seen the Persona android SDK v2 changelog
https://docs.withpersona.com/docs/android-sdk-v2-changelog

where I found the recent releases, which are working on the **latest Gradle version** which you can see by cloning **Persona Android SDK** https://github.com/persona-id/persona-android-sdk

I follow the same and the issue resolved

**Steps to resolve**

1. Update kotlin version

   ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
2. Update classpath

from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
```

3. Remove compile options

   ```
    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
   ```
4. Update the gradle-wrapper.properties to the latest 7.3.3 version

   ```
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   ```
5. At last, you need to update the persona to the latest 2.2.37

   implementation "com.withpersona.sdk2:inquiry:2.2.37"
6. Now build the project.